# Webtau - can TableData be used in a JUnit test to verify that a REST response JSON contains all given entries?

Tags: java, json, rest, junit5, webtau

[Webtau](https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau) offers, among other things, some very expressive shortcuts, like [TableData](https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/data/json#read-tabledata). I'm currently using that with JUnit. E.g. for testing expected data from a REST endpoint e.g.:

```json
[
  { "uuid": "1-2-3-4", "directionShort": "N", "direction": "North" },
  { "uuid": "1-2-3-5", "directionShort": "S", "direction": "South" },
  { "uuid": "1-2-3-6", "directionShort": "E", "direction": "East" },
  { "uuid": "1-2-3-7", "directionShort": "W", "direction": "West" }
]
```

I could write something like (yes, of course this example is a bit exagerated):

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.testingisdocumenting.webtau.WebTauDsl.http;
import static org.testingisdocumenting.webtau.Matchers.equal;
import static org.testingisdocumenting.webtau.WebTauCore.table;
import static org.testingisdocumenting.webtau.WebTauCore.____________;

http.get(URL_CARDINAL_POINTS,
    (header, body) -> {
        header.get("statusCode").shouldBe(equal(200));
        assertThat(body.isList()).isTrue();
        assertThat(body.numberOfElements()).isEqualTo(4);

        body.should(equal(table(
            "*directionShort", "direction",
            ____________,
            "N", "North",
            "S", "South",
            "E", "East",
            "W", "West"
          )));
    }
);
```

That's practicable for small sets of values. For larger data sets I'd like to test with `containAll` like e.g. this:

```json
[
  { "uuid": "...", "name": "Stockholm", "country": "Sweden", "population": 10.42 },
  { "uuid": "...", "name": "Kiew", "country": "Ukraine", "population": 10.42 },
  ...
]
```

```java
import static org.testingisdocumenting.webtau.Matchers.containAll;

http.get(URL_CAPITAL_CITIES,
    (header, body) -> {
        header.get("statusCode").shouldBe(equal(200));
        assertThat(body.isList()).isTrue();
        assertThat(body.numberOfElements()).isGreaterThan(10);

        body.should(containAll(table(
            "*name", "country", "population",
            ________________________________,
            "Paris", "France", 2.161,
            "Berlin", "Germany", 3.645,
            "Kiew", "Ukraine", 2.884,
            "Oslo", "Norway", 0.634,
            "Madrid", "Spain", 3.223
          )));
    }
);
```

### What I tried:

But that doesn't work, it fails with: `IllegalArgumentException: column 'name' is not present`.

When leaving out the key column marker (the `*` in front of "name" column), the error changes to:

```java
    body.should(containAll(table("name", "country", [...])
      -->
    "expecting body to contain all [<the table>]: no matches found for [<the table>]"
```

When using `contain()` instead of `containAll`:

```java
    body.should(contain(table("name", "country", [...])
      -->
    "AssertionError: no match found"
```

### Ugly solution:

Check "manually" for matches:

```java
    Object dataNode;
    dataNode = body.find(it -> "Paris".equals(it.get("name").get()));
    assertThat(dataNode).isNotNull();
    dataNode = body.find(it -> "Kiew".equals(it.get("name").get()));
    assertThat(dataNode).isNotNull();
    dataNode = body.find(it -> "Oslo".equals(it.get("name").get()));
    assertThat(dataNode).isNotNull();
    ...
```

which is very tedious when trying to compare more attributes other then the "key".

### Still... ugly solution:

Still far away from the expressiveness of `table`, because the keys clutter the data:

```java
import static org.testingisdocumenting.webtau.utils.CollectionUtils.map;

    body.should(containAll(
        map("name", "Paris", "country", "France", "population": 2.161),
        map("name", "Berlin", "country", "Germany", "population": 3.645),
        map("name", "Kiew", "country", "Ukraine", "population": 2.884),
        map("name", "Oslo", "country", "Norway", "population": 0.634),
        map("name", "Madrid", "country", "Spain", "population": 3.223)
    ));
```

### Question:

Is there a way to use DataTable `table` instead of the `map` sequence?

```java
  body.should(containAll(table(
      "*name", "country", "population",
      ________________________________,
      "Paris", "France", 2.161,
      "Berlin", "Germany", 3.645,
      "Kiew", "Ukraine", 2.884,
      "Oslo", "Norway", 0.634,
      "Madrid", "Spain", 3.223
  )));
```

Comment: btw, `header.get("statusCode")` has a shortcut `header.statusCode`

Comment: That's good, did not see it in documentation.
PS Oh, just found it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a good suggestion! I will have to add a new rule to WebTau to make it work. I understand the intent and it makes sense.

Syntax will be

```
body.should(contain(table))
```

This is now released: https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/HTTP/matchers#contain-table

Also super glad you are using `table`!
Feel free to join [discord server](https://discord.gg/aEHbzXTX6N), I would love to learn more about your experience, ideas and feedback.

Comment: released in 1.52: https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/release-notes/2023#1-52